# Combo box asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have datatable in Index.cshtml scaffold-ed from Bus.cs

```
    public class Bus
    {
        public int BusID { get; set; }

        public int BusOwnerID { get; set; }

        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
    }
```

In the index page i need to include a dropdownlist with BusOwnerID and BusOwnerName from BusOwner.cs

```
    public class BusOwner
    {
        public int BusOwnerID { get; set; }

        public string BusOwnerName { get; set; }

        public string Moblie { get; set; }

        public string EmailID { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller i have the following,

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Genres = db.BusOwners.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.BusOwnerID.ToString(), Text = i.BusOwnerName });

        return View(db.Buses.ToList());
    }
```

In the view, index.cshtml i need a dropdownbox with BusOwnerID and BusOwnerName. On selecting i need to display details of buses which comes under selected BusOwnerID.

I tried the following

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BusOwnerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres), "Choose... ")
```

But error occurs.

```
        CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RaspberryPi.Models.Bus>' does not contain a definition for 'BusOwnerID' and no extension method 'BusOwnerID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RaspberryPi.Models.Bus>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<RaspberryPi.Models.Bus>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Buses";
    }

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="/Buses/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create New</a>

    </div>

    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusOwnerID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectRegionId, Model.Regions, "Choose... ")


    @Html.DropDownList("drop", new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres));*@

    <div id="Ttable" style="background:#f5f5f5;position:relative;width:100%;height:25%;">
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BusTypes)</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BusTypes)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="location.href = '/Buses/Details/@item.BusID';"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-success btn-xs" onclick="location.href = '/Buses/Edit/@item.BusID';"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="location.href = '/Buses/Delete/@item.BusID';"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

How can i achieve that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Could you also provide that?

Comment: @middelpat i have edited the question with error

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

Make list of BusOwner on your view before creating Dropdown

```
var busOwnerList=BusOwner.GetAll(); //Make static method in your class to return all owner
```

now

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BusOwnerID, new SelectList(busOwnerList, "BusOwnerID", "BusOwnerName") as SelectList, "Choose... ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is no Property `BusOwnerId` present in your model.
Also the error tells us that the model is of type `IEnumerable`.

In your case `BusOwnerId` is only present on a single instance of a `Bus` and not on a collection of busses. So there are two options.

1 Return a single bus to the view as the model

instead of:

> return View(db.Buses.ToList());

Try

```
return View(db.Buses.FirstOrDefault());
```

Which will return the first bus from the database.

2 Or you could loop through each bus entry in the model and display the dropdownbox for each bus:

```
foreach(var bus in Model)
{
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => bus.BusOwnerID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres), "Choose... 
}
```

note that in the lamda i bind to `x => bus.busOwnerId` instead of `x => x.BusOwnerId` because `x.BusOwnerId` indicates that BusOwnerId is a property on the model. Which isn't because the model is a collection.